# Construct Arbitrage Portfolio and Strategy

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, finance

I have $ S_0 = 100, S_1(H) = 115, S_1(T) = 90, r=0.1 $ for a European call option with strike price $K=100$. I have constructed a replicating portfolio with $.6$  stocks and $-49.09$ bonds to find that the fair price at time $0$ is $V_0 = 10.91$. The question is: if I have the opportunity to buy this option for one dollar less than the no-arbitrage price, how do I conduct myself to get arbitrage from a starting balance of $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sell short one replicating portfolio, receiving its current value. Then, purchase one option, for a net gain of \$1. At the time of maturity, the option will always pay back the debt on the portfolio since their values will be equal by construction.